# how to create custom query method generator in spring

Tags: java, spring

Hello I want to create a custom query method generator in spring with this query

```
select * from staff where (staffName =? or tell=?) and status=1
```

and here my method

```
findByStaffNameOrTellAndStatus(String staffName, String tell, char status)
```

this query has "(" to combine condition
so if it possible​. I don't want to write query. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@Query` annotation for complex queries.